# file upload through usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, form-submit, image-uploading

i have a aspx page called uploadProject.aspx with a form and SUBMIT BUTTON
the page have a USER CONTROL PAGE with file upload and i want to save the file at the "void Submit_Click" 
at the uploadProject.aspx page

**UploadProject.aspx:**

```
  <uc1:Student1 runat="server" ID="Student1" />
    <div align="center">
        <asp:button id="Submit" runat="server" text="Submit" onclick="Submit_Click" />
    </div>
```

**Student.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Student.ascx.cs" Inherits="Student" %>
<tr>
<td>
Student Name:
</td>

<td><asp:TextBox ID="StudentNameTB" runat="server">טקסט</asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Student Name Is required" ControlToValidate="StudentNameTB" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Image URL::
</td>

<td>
<asp:FileUpload ID="StudentPhoto" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
```

i want to save the picture at UploadProject.aspx.cs
thanks

Comment: Why don't you put the Submit button in Student.ascx and handle the click event there?

Comment: i can do that but if i have a lot of files to upload , asuume one pic for every student and i have a lot of student i prefer not to press another Send button for every picture i add

Comment: So you would put many of this user controls in one page and then upload all files once?